# Beginner with slow Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics, performance, acer, sandy-bridge

I'm a beginner with Ubuntu 18.04, and I found it so slow with my Acer Aspire E1-571 laptop. How can I check if I have a problem such as a missed driver or something else? Or does my laptop lack the performance even if I don't think so?

Any help, please?

This is the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
abdelhakim@FILDSM:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: What exactly is slow? How much RAM do you have? What is graphics adapter?

Comment: I have 4gb RAM, it is slow when i use it with or withount internet but it become more slow when i open the browsers

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I did, thank you a lot for your time.

Comment: Personally I would use Ubuntu 16.04 with your hardware. It is supported until the year 2021 by which time you'll probably have a more powerful laptop.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thank you so much :)

Comment: @F.Marko You are welcome :) Although I recommend 16.04 instead of 18.04 in your case, there were two answers posted already, so I posted one as well.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend **Ubuntu 16.04** instead of 18.04 for your Sandy Bridge processor. If you would still like to use Ubuntu 18.04 there are steps you can take to make it faster. From this answer [Make Ubuntu 18.04 lighter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047169/make-ubuntu-18-04-lighter):

1. Disable or Uninstall Extensions
2. Turn Off Search Sources
3. Disable File Indexing
4. Turn Off Animations
5. Install Lighter Alternative Apps
6. Limit Startup Applications

Answer (score 0):

When you compare Ubuntu 18.04 with an older version of Ubuntu like 14.04 you will observe,

- The improvements of GUIs
- Improvements to the basic applications like VLC player, GIMP
  etc:
  So if you have work with an older version you will feel like it's slow. but it's fine.
  If still not interested try, [Speed Up Ubuntu Startup](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-ubuntu-1310/)

Comment: Another link to consider: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047169/make-ubuntu-18-04-lighter

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Acer C720 (Haswell Processor) and 18 is definitely heavier on system resources for whatever reason. RAM usage at idle on 18 is around 650MB, while 16 sits around 320. If you remove unnecessary packages (carefully!), you can lighten the load a bit. I have gotten my 16 install down to 275MB at idle (Removing drivers and unused applications).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to turn off animations. In your Dash write search for *software* and open *Software Updater*. Under *Ubuntu Software* turn on *universe* repository and click *Reload*. After that, install *Gnome Tweak Tool* with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

In *the Tweak Tool* search for *Animations* and turn it off.

[image]
[image]
[image]