# Recommendation of Ubuntu version for Acer Aspire E1-571 laptop

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, acer

I have Acer Aspire E1-571 laptop and I am using ubuntu 18.04 but it is slow and  someone recommand for me ubuntu 16.04 on this post [Beginner with slow Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1058381/816933)
but in the ubuntu website i found

Recommended system requirements:

```
2 GHz dual core processor or better
2 GB system memory
25 GB of free hard drive space
Either a DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
Internet access is helpful
```

Is it a good recommendation?

Will Ubuntu 16.04 be faster with my devices?

Comment: :Use 18.04, but K/L/Xubuntu all will run better

Comment: IMO it is a reasonable question as the OP has stated s/he is having a problem

Comment: We can't decide for you :) "it is slow" is an opinion... with those specs I would not expect wonders. I would suggest to download each of the different versions and try them out and decide what to use. Your choice also depends on what you use it for; and you did not list that. You should also look outside the Ubuntu branch though. Damn Small Linux might be an option.  For a system only to use for browsing DSL would be an excellent OS.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your [system specs](https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-aspire-e1-571-6856-15-6-core-i5-3230m-4-gb-ram-500-gb-hdd-us-international/specs/):

**CPU**

- Intel Core i5 (3rd Gen) 3230M / 2.6 GHz
- Max Turbo Speed 3.2 GHz
- Number of Cores: Dual-Core
- Cache: 3 MB
- 64-bit Computing: Yes
- Chipset Type: Mobile Intel HM77 Express
- Features: Intel Turbo Boost Technology 2.0

**RAM**

- Technology: DDR3 SDRAM
- Installed Size: 4 GB
- Max Supported Size: 8 GB
- Form Factor: SO-DIMM 204-pin
- Slots: Qty 2

**Hard Drive**

- Type: HDD
- Capacity: 500 GB

Your system specs meet the minimum requirement for Ubuntu 16.04 as stated in your question.

### Steps to modernize and improve speed

If you use Google Chrome or Firefox the best step you can take is to increase your RAM from 4 GB to 8 GB. A local computer retailer can quickly help you out with that. An additional 4 GB of RAM should cost you about $30 plus installation.

The biggest speed improvement will be upgrading your 500 GB HDD to an SSD. You can take your old HDD, put it in a $25 USB enclosure and use it for backups / slow storage. A 256 GB SSD will cost you $50 to $150 depending on sales and name branding (ie Samsung Evo 850 is name brand).

Comment: OP hasn't mentioned their system specs, or even which variant of the E1-571 they have.

Comment: @wjandrea I have a hunch the OP doesn't know the system specs nor how to find them. I took generic system specs from CNET using make and model number provided by OP. Of course it's subject to change if more details come to light but far better than the nothing. This is the second time in a month or so the OP has posted a question and hasn't got an answer from any of us. So I took 10 minutes to write one.